# What's the exact meaning of the flag MS_INVALIDATE in msync?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, filesystems, mmap

Having read the [manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/msync.html) of `msync`, I think the exact meaning of `MS_INVALIDATE` is as follows:

Provided that there are three processes *p1*, *p2*, and *p3*.

*p1* and *p2* both use `mmap` with `MAP_SHARED` to simutaneously read and write the file `/tmp/data.txt`.

*p3* uses `fread` to read the same file.

Assume that *p1* have modified the file, *p2* will immediately see the modification. However, *p3* using `fread` is not sure to see the modification.

If *p1* call `msync` with `MS_INVALIDATE|MS_SYNC` after the modification, then *p3* using `fread` is **SURE** to see the modification. That's all the meanings of the flag `MS_INVALIDATE`.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It is quite the opposite: i.e. if p3 had modified the file after p1 had mmaped it, the modification is made visible in the corresponding mapped region when p1 reads it. 'The Linux Programming Interface' by Michael Kerrisk explains this flag in detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, on linux kernel, MS_INVALIDATE actually doesn't do much, this is from [msync.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/msync.c)

The only use is this check.

```
        /* Here vma->vm_start <= start < vma->vm_end. */
        if ((flags & MS_INVALIDATE) &&
                (vma->vm_flags & VM_LOCKED)) {
            error = -EBUSY;
            goto out_unlock;
        }
```

Earlier linux systems had separate stores for I/O coming in via write/read syscalls ( aka buffer cache) and and the other one (page cache) which the mmap maps onto. However, now  Most unix based systems have a global unified cache, i.e no matter where the I/O comes from it will land up onto same in-core buffer of memory. Of course the implementation is way tricker than it seems, but MS_INVALIDATE seems to me a no-op on most UNIX based systems.

Some links:
[link1](https://linux-fsdevel.vger.kernel.narkive.com/ytPKRHNt/munmap-msync-synchronization)
[link2](https://lwn.net/Articles/712467/)